# Style bootstrap-select "placeholder" differently

Tags: jquery, html, css, placeholder, bootstrap-select

I have successfully managed to apply a different style to my normal select elements if the selected option is the first one (the placeholder) with jQuery like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready
        (
            function () 
            {
                $('select').each(function (index, value)
                {
                    if($(this).val()==="")
                    { 
                        $(this).css('font-style', 'italic');
                        $(this).css('color', '#636c72');
                        $(this).children().css('font-style', 'normal');   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).css('font-style', 'normal');
                        $(this).css('color', 'black');
                        $(this).children().css('font-style', 'normal');    
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    </script>
```

However, some of my forms are using the bootstrap-select component due to the sheer amount of entries they contain (can be thousands) and the necessity of having a way to narrow down the entries with text searches.  Those components produce MUCH more complicated HTML and the above code does not work at all.

I am trying to find a way to apply the same logic as with my normal selects : style the input in italic and with a different color if the option selected is the first one.  Here is an example of such select :

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="medFilter" name="medFilter" th:value="${medFilter}"
                                            onchange="this.form.submit()" data-live-search="true" title="Select Med"> 
                                            <option value="">Search Med</option>
                                            <option th:each="med : ${meds}" th:value="${med.id}" 
                                                th:text="${med.toString()}" th:selected="${med.id == medFilter}">
                                                </option>
                                        </select>
```

Has anyone ever been able to achieve this?

Comment: Why not do all this with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is - `bootstrap-select` replaces `<select>` to `<button>` and <`option`> to `<a>`.

That makes your code problematic for two reasons:

1. Your trying (and probably, succeeding) to style **hidden** elements (as `option` and `select` are being hidden as soon as selectpicker initiates.)
2. You're binding to `document.ready` instead of the initialization of bootstrap select.

Use CSS to set the style of the new elements instead of the old ones:

```
a.placeholder, button.bs-placeholder {
  font-style: italic !important;
  color: #636c72;
}
```

HTML (Note that `bs-placeholder` class is out-of-the-box for bootstrap-select when it doesn't have a value, you don't need to add it.):

```
<select required class="form-control selectpicker" id="medFilter" name="medFilter" title="Select Med">
      <option class="placeholder" selected value="">Search Med</option>
      <option value="med-1">Med 1</option>
      <option value="med-2">Med 2</option>
</select>
```

As long as it can be archived with css, i'd ditch the `document.ready` styling approach.

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/EAbTMz1WQnFWwtLsmYbZ?p=preview

Comment: you sir are DA MAN!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select[name=medFilter] option:eq(1)')
```

use this selector and apply your css code to this and set  as placeholder.

This will always select nth element (what u have passed in option:eq(1))

Hope this will work. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do all this with pure css, it will be more manageable than doing it with js. the following styles the input in italic and with a different color if the option selected is the first one.

I've given two examples, one with disabled and hidden, and another without disabled and hidden attributes.

```css
select option {
  color: #000000;
  font-style: normal;
}

select:invalid, select option[value=""] {
  color: red; /* Or any color you want */
  font-style: italic;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" />

<select required class="form-control selectpicker" id="medFilter" name="medFilter" title="Select Med">
  <option selected value="">Search Med</option>
  <option value="med-1">Med 1</option>
  <option value="med-2">Med 2</option>
  </option>
</select>
<select required class="form-control selectpicker" id="medFilter2" name="medFilter2" title="Select Med 2">
  <option selected disabled hidden value="">Search Med - Another</option>
  <option value="med-1">Med 1</option>
  <option value="med-2">Med 2</option>
  </option>
</select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below options

**Option 1**: Using CSS , set color and font style to select title and select first option

```css
select[title]{
  color: green;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="medFilter" name="medFilter" th:value="${medFilter}"
                                            onchange="this.form.submit()" data-live-search="true" title="Select Med"> 
                                            <option value="">Search Med</option>
                                            <option value="A">AA</option>
                                        </select>
```

**Option 2:** Using add class of jquery for select title and option first child

```js
$("select[title]").addClass('selectStyle')
```

```css
.selectStyle{
  font-style: italic;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="medFilter" name="medFilter" th:value="${medFilter}"
                                            onchange="this.form.submit()" data-live-search="true" title="Select Med"> 
                                            <option value="">Search Med</option>
                                            <option value="A">AA</option>
                                        </select>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qGrqPR

Comment: For some reason this only styles the actual option in the list and not the select element itself when that first option is selected for me.

Comment: That's because `.selectStyle` is being added to the `option` in Naga's code, and then `bootstrap-select` copies it to the `<a>` element it creates on initialization. It doesn't work the same way with `select`. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: @Martin, updated my answer to style only select option